# FirebaseUI, RecyclerView, create a reference of unknown child

Tags: android, firebase

This is my data from Firebase Console.

[image: My data]

I'm trying to create a database reference of the children inside the users UID to use them for Recycler Adapter.

DatabaseReference ref =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Offers").child(???)

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the random id, to be able to use it inside the `child()` example:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Offers").push();
String pushKey = ref.getKey();
```

then when you want to retrieve the children you can do:

```
DatabaseReference ref =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Offers").child(pushKey);
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
         for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
             String name = ds.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
           }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried to make something like this. 
String pushKey = ref.getKey(); then use this "pushKey" 
ref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Offers").child(pushKey);
And use it for for FirebaseAdapater, but still not working.

Comment: maybe because "Offers" have multiple children, this get key just return the key of the first value.